# Can't add foreign key in migration

Tags: laravel-5

I have one migration to execute. And here is my code:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->foreign('phone_id')->reference('id')->on('phone');
        });
    }
```

where i execute migration, it said i have an error in my sql. And i run `php artisan migrate --pretend` to output the sql:

```
alter table `students` add constraint `students_phone_id_foreign` foreign key (`phone_id`) references `phone` ()
```

As you can see, there is a `()` at the end of the sql. How does it come out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Schema::table('students', function ($table) {
      $table->integer('phone_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('phone_id')->references('id')->on('phones');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I worte `reference` not `references`.